# Making product on fly :

Tags: php, magento

I have store where we have different type of Chars : C1, C2, C3 and Tables: T1, T2 ,T3

Now user have option to buy C1 as seprtae product or T1 with C1 / C2 / C3 as new product

Now what i did :

There is product listing page of all chairs and user have option to buy Chair or chosse a table for chair, now when user selects choose table for chair , he will be redirected to page where he can see Chair C1 with table T1 and so on all combinations. I wrote custom code to show price of T1C1 (T1 + C1) just by check previous product id using some parameters but in actual there is no product T1C1 if user add product to cart i want fly product T1C1 gets added and price (= T1 + C1) also in his order.

How can i do it

Answer (score 0):

Create grouped product with your suitable combination.